# Kendo UI grid: does grouping cause the dataSource change event to fire, by design?

Tags: grid, datasource, kendo-ui, onchange

When I group by dragging a column header to the grouping panel, the change event of the dataSource fires.  Is this by design?

EDIT: The event also happens when the grid is sorted by a column.

Part of the basis for my question is that the word "changes" is ambiguous. I've been reading documentation for a long time and sometimes authors want the word to mean "undergoes modification" and sometimes they want it to mean "is replaced".  Some Windows controls software houses distinguish between the two scenarios by using separate words,  "modified" and "changed" and name their events accordingly. So it's not always clear what is intended.

"Change your undershorts".  There it means "put on a new pair of undershorts", not "sew a button on the pair of undershorts you're wearing."

If the kendo dataSource.change event fires by design when grouping and sorting occur, how to distinguish between those two "non-essential" changes ( the data haven't been modified, they're just in a different order) and the scenario where the grid's underlying dataset is replaced in its entirety? Is there a way to "listen" for a dataSource.dataCompletelyReplaced scenario?  Compare a DataSourceChanged event on many WinForms grids, which event fires **not** when an item in the dataset is changed but when the dataset is *supplanted* and the grid is rebound.

"Undergoes change" and "is supplanted" are very different scenarios.

In the Kendo grid, an example might be where the grid is initialized in the configuration with an empty array `dataSource.data = []` and then later, possibly but not necessarily after some user interaction, the empty array is replaced with an actual dataset using `dataSource.data(someNewData)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the change event of the DataSource is supposed to fire when data is grouped (or sorted, filtered etc). Groping is a data operation which changes the DataSource's view - current state of the data items.

There is no separate build-in event that will trigger after a "dataCompletelyReplaced" action. If you are editing (or inserting) particular record you may use the "action" parameter of the event data.

```
$("#grid").data("kendoGrid")
    .dataSource.bind("change", function(e) { 
        e.action 
    });
```